# Does VS Code extensions API support changing cursor position?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to know if the extension API support *changing cursor position*. I tried to find in the API reference but I couldn't find related function.

The reason behind such function is that

- I normally spend much time to move the cursor while writing source code. (by pressing arrow key, home key, pgUp, etc)
- So, if I can write an extension that could change cursor location effectively, that could save time a lot. :-)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

there is a command named `cursorMove` which can be run from an extension. In this example the extension uses `showInputBox` to prompt for the number of lines to move. Then `vscode.commands.executeCommand` is run to execute the `cursorMove` command to move down by the entered number of lines:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode' ;

let lastNumLines = '1';

// -------------------------- registerCommand_moveCursor --------------------------
export function registerCommand_moveCursor(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)
{
    const fullExtensionName = `sample.moveCursorDown`;
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(fullExtensionName, async ( ) =>
    {
        const val = await vscode.window.showInputBox(
                    { prompt: 'number lines to move', value: lastNumLines });

        if (val)
        {
            lastNumLines = val ;
            const numLines = Number(val) ;

            await vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove",
                {
                    to: "down", by:'wrappedLine', value:numLines
                });
        }
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext)
{
    registerCommand_moveCursor(context) ;
}
```

package.json

```
    "contributes": {

            "commands": [
                {
                    "command": "sample.moveCursorDown",
                    "title": "move cursor down",
                    "category": "sample"   
                }
            ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just directly set the `selection` field of the [TextEditor object](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor) (or `selections` to work with multiple cursors).

Example - this shifts each cursor to the left one character:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const newSelections = [];

for (const selection of editor.selections) {
    const oldCursorPosition = selection.start;
    const newCursorPosition = new vscode.Position(
        oldCursorPosition.line,
        Math.max(0, oldCursorPosition.character - 1)
    );

    // We set start & end to the same Position, so this is setting a cursor position,
    // not a selected range of text
    const newSelection = new vscode.Selection(newCursorPosition, newCursorPosition);
    newSelections.push(newSelection);
}

editor.selections = newSelections;
```

Comment: Notice, `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` may be `undefined`.